# How to Troubleshoot NSLayoutConstraint errors?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UITableView in my App. It populates a Custom UITableCell called as Lesson Cell. It will look like this http://i.imgur.com/VoCxkJa.png

Whenever this view loads. It shows a bunch of layout errors like below. But it looks fine on my `Interface Builder`. I researched & tried a lot to solve this error.

Please help me out. Thanks in Advance

```
2015-08-17 12:25:51.543 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85706d4150 UILabel:0x7f85706eb5c0'How Old are You?'.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85706ce730.leadingMargin + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85706c6450 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85706ce730.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f85706eb5c0'How Old are You?'.trailing + 50>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85706e7710 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85706ce730(34)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85706c6450 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85706ce730.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f85706eb5c0'How Old are You?'.trailing + 50>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**EDIT**

I use Dynamic Table View Cell in my View Controller. May be this cause any issue ?

```
   LessonTable.estimatedRowHeight = 120
   LessonTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Please refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885421/how-to-fix-strange-nslayoutconstraint-errors-that-dont-seem-to-effect-layout-in

Comment: I have already seen that one. But it doesn't work for me...

Comment: what is fittingSizeHTarget ?

Answer (score 0):

You are have a conflict of constraints for `UILabel:0x7f85706eb5c0'How Old are You?'.trailing + 50>` for easy fix it for your case just add priority for hugging UILabel.

From code:

```
[urLabelCell setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[urLabelCell setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[urLabelCell setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[urLabelCell setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

or in IB:

[image]

And genereal remove one of this rule:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85706d4150 UILabel:0x7f85706eb5c0'How Old are You?'.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85706ce730.leadingMargin + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f85706c6450 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f85706ce730.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f85706eb5c0'How Old are You?'.trailing + 50>",
```

or set different priority